# check if one vector<int> can be nested in another

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, containers, c++17

I'm trying out challenges on Edabit and the current challenge is about nesting vectors. the instructions are:
Create a function that returns true if the first array can be nested inside the second.

Array 1 can be nested inside Array 2 if:

1. Array 1's min > Array 2's min.
2. Array 1's max < Array 2's max.

examples:

```
canNest([1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 6]) ➞ true

canNest([3, 1], [4, 0]) ➞ true

canNest([9, 9, 8], [8, 9]) ➞ false

canNest([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3]) ➞ false
```

the code I've written, which does not pass all the tests is the following:

```
bool canNest(std::vector<int> arr1, std::vector<int> arr2) {
    return (std::min_element(arr1.begin(), arr1.end()) > 
                 std::min_element(arr2.begin(), arr2.end()) && 
                 std::max_element(arr1.begin(), arr1.end()) < 
                 std::max_element(arr2.begin(), arr2.end()));
}
```

This code makes test3, test4 and test5 pass, but not for test1 and test2.

```
    It(test1){Assert::That(canNest({1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 6}), Equals(true));}
    It(test2){Assert::That(canNest({3, 1}, {4, 0}), Equals(true));}
    It(test3){Assert::That(canNest({9, 9, 8}, {8, 9, 10}), Equals(false));}
    It(test4){Assert::That(canNest({9, 9, 8}, {8, 9}), Equals(false));}
    It(test5){Assert::That(canNest({1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3}), Equals(false));}
```

EDIT: the challenge can be found [here](https://edabit.com/challenge/8rnwPLFtuPLDbJmt3), for testing the solution!

Comment: As I recall, you have to dereference min_element and max_element with*: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/

Comment: Is coming to a forum like this asking for others to help you solve the problem missing the spirit of the challenge?

Comment: min/max_element return an iterator, deference them

Comment: @dyukha you were right! it worked

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts you too btw!

Comment: As stated in the documentation of [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element), and[`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element), they return iterators, and **not** elements.

Comment: Notice that with `std::minmax_element` you can do a little better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the algorithms you use return iterators that need to be dereferenced. For this task, you should probably look at their companion, `std::minmax_element` that return iterators to both the min and max element to not have to go through the lists many times:

```
bool canNest(const std::vector<int>& arr1, const std::vector<int>& arr2) {
    auto [min1, max1] = std::minmax_element(arr1.begin(), arr1.end());
    auto [min2, max2] = std::minmax_element(arr2.begin(), arr2.end());

    return *min1 > *min2 && *max1 < *max2;
}
```

An alternative is to only acquire *min* and *max* for the enclosing vector and to use an algorithm that will return `false` early if it the overall condition can't be met. It could possibly be more effective, especially on big datasets.

```
bool canNestImproved(const std::vector<int>& arr1, const std::vector<int>& arr2) {
    auto [min2it, max2it] = std::minmax_element(arr2.begin(), arr2.end());

    // all elements in arr1 must fall within the boundaries and std::all_of
    // will stop iterating over arr1 as soon as the lambda returns false.
    return std::all_of(
        arr1.begin(), arr1.end(),
        [min2 = *min2it, max2 = *max2it](int x) { return x > min2 && x < max2; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as Dyukha said in the comments min/max_element return an iterator and you need to dereference them.

```
bool canNest(std::vector<int> arr1, std::vector<int> arr2) {
    return (*std::min_element(arr1.begin(), arr1.end()) > 
                 *std::min_element(arr2.begin(), arr2.end()) && 
                 *std::max_element(arr1.begin(), arr1.end()) < 
                 *std::max_element(arr2.begin(), arr2.end()));
}
```